# XML data not appearing in HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, xml, ajax, django

I'm trying to get XML data to appear on an HTML page. I'm using Django to generate the content in the XML file, and Javascript to ping back every five seconds to see if there have been new posts to load them into the page.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <tr>
            <td class="username">{{ post.username }}</td>
            <td class="message">{{ post.message }}</td>
            <td class="timestamp">[{{ post.timestamp }}] </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
function setupRequest(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var posts = document.getElementById('posts');
    var i;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readState != 4){
            return ;
        }
        console.log("hello",request);
        var XMLData = request.response
        posts.innerHTML = XMLData;
        // setTimeout("setupRequest()", 5000);
    }
    request.open("GET","/chat/grab/", true);
    request.send();
}
function init(){
    console.log('Init');
    setupRequest()
}


window.onload=init;
```

And here is the output from my Chrome console:

```
client.js:18Init
chrome-extension://iljkdiphoadeehmlplkjgjpojdpdfgfa/content.js:1starting content
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="box">
<table id="posts">
</table>

</div>
```

However, nothing's appearing in the page itself. Anyone have any ideas? I have no idea what's happening...

Thank you!

Comment: In what way is that XML? It's an HTML fragment. That doesn't actually make any difference as far as the Javascript is concerned, but you should call things what they are.

Comment: You can put anything into XML; I have HTML fragments in it because after the code is generation by Django, it makes sense within the table with the id 'posts'. It /is/ an XML document.

Comment: Yes, I know you can put HTML fragments into XML, I'm just wondering why. There's nothing in your Javascript that needs XML rather than just HTML. It's perfectly possible to do "Ajax" with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

`request.readState`

should be

`request.readyState`

readState is always not equal to 4.

Comment: It appears now! Thank you so much marteljn!